# 500 Internal Server Error - Form Validation (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, validation

So, basically I tried to create form validation in Laravel, in this case is the Registration Form Validation. I tried to create this validation using Request Class. The problem is, the validation doesn't work for the email and username field, which are the unique (both of the fields) and email format validation. Instead, I got this error. Other fields validation works fine.

Before I decided to give a try on using Request Class, I've tried to validate inside the controller and it just works fine. I have no idea why this method doesn't work.

**register.blade.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/register-style.css">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<title>Register</title>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">          
        <div class="container">             
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">

                </div> 
                <div id="form-input">    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1"name="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputConfPassword1">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputConfPassword1" name="password_confirmation">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="btnRegister" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnRegister">Register</button>

            </form> 
            <a href="/">Back to login menu</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="/js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/register-script.js"></script>
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        return view('register');
    }

    public function insertNewUser(RegisterRequest $req){        
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'email' => $req['email'],
            'username' => $req['username'],
            'password' =>  Hash::make($req['password'])
        ]);

        return response()->json(['response' => 'success']);
    }

}
```

**RegisterRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        ];

    }

}
```

Beside the 500 error that displayed on the browser's console, I also got the error message in the Laravel log:

```
[2019-08-07 13:27:04] local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::validated does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Http\\Request::validated does not exist.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have typo: `$validated = $req->validated();` try with: `$validated = $req->validate()`

Comment: Which version of laravel are you running? if i remember ```->validated()``` was added to FormRequests somewhere around version 5.5?

Comment: @RobbinBenard I'm using Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already using request class then it will automatically apply the rules into your post request (dependency injection), you don't need to call it again inside ValidateRegister

```
 public function ValidateRegister(RegisterRequest $req){
    return $this->insertNewUser(
        $req['email'],
        $req['username'],
        Hash::make($req['password'])
    );
}
```

and eventually, that function is unnecessary at all and waste of lines

you can combine it in your insertNewUser function

```
public function insertNewUser(RegisterRequest $req){        
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'email' => $req['email'],
        'username' => $req['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($req['password'])
    ]);

    return response()->json(['response' => 'success']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a form request, you don't need `$validated = $req->validated();` in a controller. When the custom request class is injected, the validation will run itself before the request data will reach the controller.

And to make your request class a little cleaner, you don't need `confirmPassword` field there. Just use `confirmed` rule for `password` and rename your `confirmPassword` field to `password_confirmation` in your form and it will work.

Comment: he's using confirmPassword as field name, so he needs to edit in blade to make it as password_confirmation, because confirmed validation means you need _confirmation as related field name

Comment: @GhiffariAssamar agreed. He should be avoiding non-standard practices.

Comment: @Rehmat I have followed your instruction for the confirm password rule but it doesn't work though, it keeps validating that both password & confirm password does not match.

Comment: @StanleyL Can you please update your question with your form code and the request code?

Comment: @Rehmat it also doesn't validate that the confirm password field is required.

Comment: @StanleyL I suspect you aren't passing `password_confirmation` correctly. If you are using Ajax to post, can I have a look at your Ajax code? Otherwise I can't see method attached to your form. Regarding the required attribute, it is already required as the validation will fail if `password_confirmation` field doesn't have the same value as the `password` field.

Comment: @Rehmat Ah, my bad. I wasn't aware that there is something wrong in my ajax code. I didn't pass the password_confirmation field correctly because i haven't changed the json field from confirmPassword to password_validation. Anyway, thanks for helping me to figure it out!

Comment: @StanleyL Good to know that you sorted it out :)